# Automatic drag an ".draggable" element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

Is it possible to make an automatic drag (whitout mouse-drag) with jquery draggable?

I´m thinking:
Load elements from db using php.
Find element with jquery and move it to position stored in db.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function){
  $('#element').draggable({
    automatic move to position:
      top: 22
      left: 22                    
});
```

How else should i load my stored element positions?
I drag elements from one div to another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the position of your element with css.

For example:

```
$(document).ready(function){
    $('#element').draggable();
    $('#element').css({'top': x, 'left' : y});
});
```

Take a look at this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/n0qovynq/1/)

Hope it may helps you.

Comment: This looks like the way i must go. Thank you!